# Jailbroken iphone 4S stuck in recovery mode after iOS update

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I started an iOS update, on my jailbroken iPhone 4s, via **Settings** and now the iPhone is stuck in recovery mode. iTunes just wants to restore, but if I do this I will lose all my data and I don't have a backup.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have lost all your content. You cannot perform an OVA update when jail broken. The only way to update is to use iTunes Restore and then re-jailbreak once it has successfully updated your device. Naturally you will require a backup to restore to.

Answer (score 1):

Updating iOS at all on your jailbroken iPhone (including OTA) will break everything. You will not be able to recover your data from the device and you should restore in iTunes. Once restored, restore from your iCloud/iTunes backup if necessary and re-jailbreak.

Answer (score -2):

You can exit the recovery mode by:

Assuming you're running on Windows:

1. Google TinyUmbrella.
2. Download it.
3. Connect your iPhone
4. Click Exit Recovery
5. Done.

Comment: This won't work since you can't get out of recovery mode when it's happened for a reason. This is for getting out of recovery mode when you've put it in recovery mode yourself.

Comment: In addition to @grgarside's reply, this user started to update his iPhone. The software is corrupt now and trying to Exit Recovery cannot fix this issue.