# iPad 3 stuck in recovery mode

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios

I jailbroke this iPad sometime ago and just updated it to 7.1.2, it's now stuck in recovery mode and won't come out even though I tried the button pressing method.

There's a lot of photos on it that wasn't backed up, is there a way to get the iPad out of recovery mode or retrieve the data inside it?

Comment: What do you mean by the button pressing mode,is it the DFU mode?

Comment: I don't think it is in DFU mode cause it has the connect to itunes icon, and what I meant by the button pressing method is the one where you press the home button and lock button together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may pull you out of recovery, but it will clean wipe the iPad. [Download](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) the Latest ipsw supported by your iPad. Put the iPad into [DFU mode](http://www.iphonehacks.com/put-iphone-in-dfu-mode). Open iTunes and press the restore button holding the <kbd>option</kbd> + Restore if on a mac, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Restore if on PC and select the downloaded ipsw file.

P.S: Try [this](http://www.leawo.org/ios-data-recovery/) for recovery, it is a paid software. I haven't tried this personally, but the software description says that it can recover data from an iDevice stuck in recovery

Comment: I think my situation is more like this guy's http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90492/jailbroken-iphone-4s-stuck-in-recovery-mode-after-ios-update?rq=1

Comment: Yes, That´s why I say there is almost no chance of recovering the data, but you can make the iPad usable once again.

Comment: Couldn't I get out of recovery mode by just clicking restore in itunes? do I need to go through the steps you said in order to get it working?

Comment: Try to do that, even if does bring you out, it will be a new updated version and there is a chance of issues as your device was previously jailbroken.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I will use your method to restore if there is no other method to get the data back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution I got to keep all my stuff it's the last one on the page https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4310336?start=60&tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your reference?